# Problem with mpmath under Python 3.8, but OK under 2.7

Tags: python, mpmath

The following lttle program fails using Python 3.8, but is OK under 2.7:

```
from mpmath import mpf, nsum

def z(n):
    x = [mpf(1) for k in range(1,n)]
    return 99

print (nsum(z, [2,2]))
```

The code looks odd, as it is pared down from a rather larger program.  I can't pare it down any further.  This can be confirmed easily using the interactive shell at https://www.python.org/shell/

The error report is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/extrapolation.py", line 1698, in nsum
    return +g()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/extrapolation.py", line 1745, in <lambda>
    return False, lambda: f(*([0]*len(intervals)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpmath/calculus/extrapolation.py", line 1777, in g
    s += f(*args)
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in z
TypeError: 'mpf' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

`nsum` passes `n` as [mpf](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/blob/981102736a843ae30c26f73b388fdba622a46270/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py#L39) to `z`, but [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) expects:

> ...int or any object that implements the __index__ special method.

So you could cast `n` explicitly to `int`, e.g.:

```
x = [mpf(1) for k in range(1, int(n))]
```